# Induction Cooktop Tripping Breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a technika induction cooktop on its own dedicated 32A circuit. Nothing new been in the house 7 years and nothing has changed.
Breaker keeps tripping when I flick the isolator switch before I’ve even turned the hobs. Have tested and power is running from the board>board to isolator>isolator to plug socket and can’t access the other side at the moment but assuming it was as last night it work turn on then trip. Now it’s just tripping when I turn the isolator switch.
Have tested the switch - between line and load on insulation and reading 550kohm. Can’t remember if this is good? No visible evidence of burning/loose terminations etc. any advice? Thanks

Comment: what is a isolator switch ?

Comment: Does the thing that is tripping have a "test" button on it?

Comment: UK wiring, @Ruskes, often has a switch for each outlet. I'm reasonably certain that this is what the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Inductive cooktops run using high frequency.

the line voltage is converted to high freq. the electronics are usually powered all the time for instant on.

You may have the controls turned off but there is still leakage causing the breaker to trip, when you isolate it it no longer trips.

DC measurements with an ohm meter are not always helpful unless checking the front to back ratio on the SCR’s and triac’s for the individual leads.

this level troubleshooting is beyond basic DiY but the fact that it is tripping each time it is connected to the mains power shows there is a problem.

At this point having it checked out by an appliance repair or warranty repair is your best option.